# How open a NEW window (a music player) and host it in a Shopify environment

Tags: javascript, html, shopify

In a Shopify shop, I am currently using:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function popupwindow(url, winName, w, h) {
  var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
  var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
  return window.open(url, winName, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
} 
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="popupwindow('example.html', 'musicPlayer',800,350 ); return false;">NEW CENTERED POPUP WIN</a>
```

to open a music player in a new window, but the 'example.html' file is hosted on another server because I cant figure out where to put it within Shopify.

It functions well, but example.html is in a different domain - and modern browers are begining to stop x-domain audio from auto-playing.

I've tried uploading example/html into the Shopify 'file' structure. But this has a domain of "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/...." so same problem.

I can put the whole code into a 'snippet' in the 'Theme' area, but:

a) It says it exceeds the 256k limit!

b) I can't think of how to call it from an '< a link

Answer (score 0):

A Shopify file asset should work fine for you. It is not subject to any kind of browser rules as you state, since it is a child of the window object and the window has permissions on the domain. If what you were saying was true, imagine all content distribution server assets would be triggering these warnings. I have plenty of customers that stream music via popups and regular html elements, and the music is all sourced out of file assets.

Comment: I am using:
<a href="#" onclick="popupwindow('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/...' so at the top of the (new) window it shows the url as "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/..." and e.g. chrome doesn't auto play as this is a different domain than the shop.

Comment: Perhaps I should add:  I have html5 <audio> tags working fine with mp3 files stored in 'shopify files'.  It's only when I have a new window I have the issue.

Comment: @user:210841 says "the music is all sourced out of file assets."  It's not the sourcing of the music files that is my real question.  It's where I source/host/file the code to open and write the new window.